# Prove a case of Dirichlet's Theorem: that there are infinitely many primes of the form $8k+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove a case of Dirichlet's Theorem: that there are infinitely many primes of the form $8k+1$ using these steps.

*(Dirichlet’s Theorem). Let $a$, $b$ be two positive integers. If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, then there exists an infinite number of primes of the form $ak + b$.*

> The aim of this exercise is to prove Dirichlet's Theorem when $a = 8$ and $b = 1$.
>   Let $x$ be an even integer and $p$ be a prime divisor of $x^4+1$.
>
> 1. Show that $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = 1$.
> 2. Prove that $x$ and $p$ are coprime and deduce that $x$ is invertible modulo $p$.
> 3. Show that $\left(\frac2p\right) = 1$.  Hint: You might find the following identity useful:
>      $$ x^4+1 = (x^2+1)^2-2x^2 $$
> 4. Show that $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$.
> 5. Deduce that there are infinitely many primes $p$ congruent to $1$ modulo $8$.

So far I've got
$N = (2p_1p_2\ldots p_r)^4+1$

Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $N$. If $p|N$ then

$$p| (2p_1p_2\ldots p_r)^4+1$$

$$-1 = (2p_1p_2\ldots p_r)^4 \mod p$$

$$(-1/p) = 1$$

This is where I get stuck.

My lecturer has replied with:

'This is indeed the beginning of the correct answer. You have that N is of the form x^4+1, so you can use question 4) and deduce N=1 mod 8. Now, can it be equal to one of the p_i?'

I'm still unsure where to go from here?

Comment: that a wonderful exercise. Have you **tried** anything or are you just asking us to do to everything for you? (in that case i m sorry to say it won't happen)

Comment: please type this in the question's body. It would help people to understand where you are stuck.

Comment: Edit your question to show your attempts, rather than just posting a picture. Also, write down the question rather than pointing to a picture as well. Then, state Dirichlet's theorem yourself to begin with.

Comment: You might want to look at the [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) of the referenced theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by "Prove *using* Dirichlet's Theorem"?

Comment: Sorry I meant prove Dirichlet's Theorem

Comment: OP: I've inlined the question in your image.  Please check that it matches your intent, and if it does, then you can remove the link.

Comment: @MayurChauhan, I figured that's what you meant. In general, I find it helpful in my own work, especially when I'm stuck, to go back over what I've written and ask myself if I've said *precisely* what I meant to say. It doesn't always help get me unstuck, but at least it gives me something to do while my subconscious is grinding away. (You might also do something along these lines by learning how to use dollar signs to make the paragraph with your lecturer's reply look nice. Learning some TeX will help you in the future.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help fill in the details. Let us write $x = 2p_1\ldots p_r$, for some finite $r$, where $p_1 \ldots p_r$ are in Teri's answer, all the primes that are 1 mod 8. Then as Teri already noted there is a prime $p$ that divides $x^4+1$, and $p \not \in \{p_1,\ldots, p_r\}$. We claim that $p$ is of the form $8k+1$ for some integer $k$ next. As already noted by Teri, this will imply that $p_1,\ldots, p_r$ are not all the primes that are 1 mod 8, which will give you what you want.

Note that

$$x^4+1 \equiv_p 0 \Rightarrow x^4 \equiv_p -1 \Rightarrow x^8 \equiv_p 1;$$

That $x^4 \not \equiv_p 1$ and $x^8 \equiv_p 1$, together imply that $x$ has order **precisely** 8 in the group $\left(\mathbb{F}_p\right)^{\times}$, which implies that $|\left(\mathbb{F}_p\right)^{\times}| = p-1$ is divisible by 8, which implies that $p$ is of the form $8k+1$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: So how would I be able to use this to go through each exercise in the original question?

Comment: I'm not sure. This will establish the main result though, which I would imagine should be fine with your instructor

Comment: +1 for formatting the maths so that it's comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already answered the question

Suppose that there are only finitely many such primes p1,…,pk≡1(mod8). Then consider the following number
(2p1⋯pk)4+1,
which is coprime with each pi, and has remainder 1 modulo 8. Since it is odd and greater than 1, it has to be divisible by an odd prime p. Then
ordp(2p1⋯pk)=8
which divides φ(p)=p−1 by Fermat's theorem. Therefore p is another prime ≡1(mod8).

Comment: How do you get $p\equiv1\pmod 8$?

Comment: This is one of the sub questions to my original problem. Not sure how he got that???

Comment: $x^4+1$ is the $8$-th cyclotomic polynomial so every prime $p$ dividing it has to be $1\pmod 8$. Also by Fermat's Little theorem (and Lagrange's group theorem), $a^(p-1) = 1 \pmod p$, so the order of $a \pmod p$ divides $p-1$ (for any prime $p$). As $a^8-1 = (a^4+1)(a^4-1)$, $a^4+1$ does not divide $a^k-1$ for any $k$ smaller than $8$. So if $p$ divides $a^4+1$, then $8$ divides the order of $a \pmod p$. We conclude that $p = 1\pmod 8$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that all odd and prime divisors of n4+1 have the form 8k+1. Suppose that there are just finite prime numbers of form 8k+1. Construct the number a=(2p1…pn)4+1, where {pi}ni=1are all primes of form 8k+1. This number is odd, and has at least one prime divisor q. Then q has the form 8l+1. But then q=pj for some j. But it is not possible since q divides a and q divides (2p1…pn)4, i.e, q divides 1.

Comment: How do you know that $q\equiv1\pmod 8$?

Answer (score 0):

My proof goes like this:

Assume by way of contradiction that there are only finitely many of such prime numbers, say $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_r$. Consider $p=16(p_1p_2\cdot \cdot\cdot p_r)^4+1=(2p_1p_2\cdot \cdot \cdot p_r)^4+1$. Recall that the congruence $x^4 \equiv -1 \pmod {p}$ is solvable if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$. $p$ cannot be a prime of the form $8n+1$, but $p \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, there is a contradiction. Thus, there must be infinitely many prime numbers of the form $8n+1$.

Comment: Good answer, I saw this just after I posted mine